# can mod_muc using external auth_method? (ejabberd)

Tags: ejabberd

I am trying make chatting program using ejabberd, and I'm success to single and group chatting room. and I try to create secret group chatting room that was not using static password.

If client want join secret chatting room, client send hash_key that encrypted by secret code to ejabberd server.  and ejabberd server try parsing that hash_key by secret code using php or other external programs.

Because I have another server and that server is not related to ejabberd server. so my client join to chatting by anonymous account authenticated by external php program. and i want to control user group by my another server using secret hash_key. that is my plan.

I need help. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For account login in ejabberd you can use extauth.

But, for user join a mod_muc room, the password is static, and stored by that room. So, external authentication for the password to join a private room is not possible.